# Unable to launch aws instance using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

While running terraform script, it shows the following error

```
Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound: The key pair 'oregonkeypair' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 921dcb14-796f-4d80-9d41-295dd2fffde7

  on instances.tf line 5, in resource "aws_instance" "rest":
   5: resource "aws_instance" "rest" {



Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound: The key pair 'oregonkeypair' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: f35fc4f3-994c-4e32-9120-03ef02de952f

  on instances.tf line 19, in resource "aws_instance" "connect":
  19: resource "aws_instance" "connect" {



Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound: The key pair 'oregonkeypair' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 5127a96f-e64b-4a34-bea8-cb848b8b82f8

  on instances.tf line 33, in resource "aws_instance" "ksql":
  33: resource "aws_instance" "ksql" {



Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound: The key pair 'oregonkeypair' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 72dd21a3-62b6-4e65-bf17-c68dafd885fa

  on instances.tf line 46, in resource "aws_instance" "control_center":
  46: resource "aws_instance" "control_center" {



Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound: The key pair 'oregonkeypair' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 06d12048-f2ee-44a9-9bc4-0b69619040c6

  on instances.tf line 60, in resource "aws_instance" "schema":
  60: resource "aws_instance" "schema" {
```

Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound: The key pair 'oregonkeypair' does not exist
status code: 400, request id: 9c49141d-7b47-490f-96d8-364399567244

```
But the same key is in the same folder and also provided chmod 400 permission
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined the key as a separate resource as stated in the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#key_name).

> key_name - (Optional) Key name of the Key Pair to use for the
> instance; which can be managed using the aws_key_pair resource.

As far as I understand it, you will need to define it in your template, see [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/key_pair)

Example:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "deployer" {
   key_name   = "deployer-key"
   public_key = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y...and-so-on...1 email@example.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This keypair `oregonkeypair` should already exist in AWS or create one using terraform as mentioned by @Ben

A quick fix would be to create one manually in AWS Console https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home